# Swift 4 json decoder error flickr

Tags: json, swift, json-deserialization, swift4

I am trying out the new JSONDecoder() in swift 4 and am trying to parse the following flickr API response : (https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?api_key=api_key&method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&per_page=25&text=hello&nojsoncallback=1).  However I get an error saying that "error processing json data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."  However the data seems to be in the correct format to me.  Am I doing anything wrong?

```
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                } else if let data = data {
                    print(response)
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        print(data)
                        let flickrPhotos = try decoder.decode(FlickrImageResult.self, from: data)
                    } catch {
                        dump(data)
                        print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
```

My data models are

```
struct FlickrImageResult : Codable {
     var photos : FlickrPhoto? = nil

}

struct FlickrPhoto : Codable {
    var photo : [FlickrURLs]? = nil
 }

struct FlickrURLs: Codable {
    var id : String? = nil
    var owner: String? = nil
    var secret: String? = nil
    var server: String? = nil
    var farm: String? = nil
}
```

I changed the number of images requested to 2 and Printing out the data returns 
        Optional({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":120197,"perpage":2,"total":"240393","photo":[{"id":"36729752762","owner":"152440263@N02","secret":"e62ba3e18b","server":"4432","farm":5,"title":"Hello there","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36729384952","owner":"141041947@N06","secret":"bc0e5af630","server":"4380","farm":5,"title":"POST\ud83d\udd25 #891 | Hello Tuesday | Krescendo","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})

Comment: Does it show the correct JSON string if you just print the `data` from the URL response?

Comment: So the response is returning 200 and printing data returns 4694 bytes
so I assume there is something there.

Comment: try `print(String(bytes:data, encoding: .utf8) )` to see what's actually there

Comment: I was just doing that thanks!  And it does return the correct data I added it to the question.

Comment: Answer updated with paged response.

Comment: It looks like it thinks `data` is optional even though you unwrapped it. Try using a different name such as `else if let jsonData = data {` and then change `data` to `jsonData` in your `decode(...)` call.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only problem with your model is that `farm` is actually an `Int`. Here's a more complete version of your model accoirding to the docs (https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html):

```
struct FlickrImageResult: Codable {
    let photos : FlickrPagedImageResult?
    let stat: String
}

struct FlickrPagedImageResult: Codable {
    let photo : [FlickrURLs]
    let page: Int
    let pages: Int
    let perpage: Int
    let total: String
}

struct FlickrURLs: Codable {
    let id : String
    let owner: String
    let secret: String
    let server: String
    let farm: Int
    // let title: String
    // If needed, camel-case and use CodingKeys enum
    //let ispublic: Int
    //let isfriend: Int
    //let isfamily: Int
}

let jsonData = """
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 13651,
    "perpage": 25,
    "total": "341263",
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "36499638920",
        "owner": "55126206@N07",
        "secret": "7e82dee0ba",
        "server": "4346",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "[BREATHE]-Ririko,Sayaka&Chiyoko",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "36724435032",
        "owner": "92807782@N04",
        "secret": "6d830d4a75",
        "server": "4354",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Serendipity Designs @ SWANK August 2017",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "36087089863",
        "owner": "152685136@N08",
        "secret": "a4a3f2fe0a",
        "server": "4365",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Hello Kitty Scooter",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "36086949593",
        "owner": "151818203@N02",
        "secret": "fc1207d373",
        "server": "4334",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Hip, Hip! It's Chip!",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "36498504410",
        "owner": "148300038@N02",
        "secret": "5c7f6ff3e1",
        "server": "4391",
        "farm": 5,
        "title": "Hello Kotti",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let flickrPhotos = try! JSONDecoder().decode(FlickrImageResult.self, from: jsonData)
print(flickrPhotos)
```

P.S: The message `error processing json data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.` is the localized error message, **use `print(error)` instead of `print(errorlocalizedDescription)`** to obtain all the error data available (in your case, it will print that there's an issue when trying to decode the farm key).

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help. However when I plug in the above and put it in a do catch block it still give me the error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." Could it be a swift 4 problem?
  do {
            let flickrPhotos = try JSONDecoder().decode(FlickrImageResult.self, from: jsonData)
            print(flickrPhotos)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

Comment: The whole example works: Check here for live eval http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59a5c3e452eabe5bb8de608f (Playgrounds/Empty iOS app also)

Comment: Thank you very much! It must be something in my project!

Comment: Nevermind, it was a JSON encoding issue (farm is an Int not String). When you are debugging, never use `error.localizedDescription` but `print("json error: \(error)")` instead. It will provide more information.

Comment: The only issue with your model was that farm needs to be an Int (answer updated).